# Shared keys in repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, key, shared, anova, rstatix

I am trying to preform a repeated measures ANOVA in R with `anova_test` from the `rstatix` package. However I got the error shared keys in 98 rows.

**The dataframe**

In total I have 264 observations, in which I can select `LOCATION` (3), `WATERLEVEL` (11), `TRAJECT` (2), `MEASUREMENT` (2).

```
 dput(flux_CO2_bare_columns[1:11])
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), LOCATION = c("Z", 
"Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", 
"V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", 
"V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", 
"A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", 
"A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", 
"Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", 
"A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", 
"Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", 
"V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", 
"V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", 
"A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "V", "V", "V", "A", 
"A", "A"), COLUMN = c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", 
"A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", 
"Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", 
"Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", 
"V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", 
"A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", 
"Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", 
"V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", 
"A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", 
"Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", 
"Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", 
"V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", 
"A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", 
"Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "V1", "V2", 
"V3", "A1", "A2", "A3"), GRASS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), TRAJECT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), MEASUREMENT = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), DATE = structure(c(1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 
1642377600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 1642377600, 1642550400, 1642550400, 
1642550400, 1642550400, 1642550400, 1642550400, 1642550400, 1642550400, 
1642550400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 
1642982400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 1642982400, 1643155200, 1643155200, 
1643155200, 1643155200, 1643155200, 1643155200, 1643155200, 1643155200, 
1643155200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 
1643587200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 1643587200, 1643760000, 1643760000, 
1643760000, 1643760000, 1643760000, 1643760000, 1643760000, 1643760000, 
1643760000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 
1644192000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 1644192000, 1644364800, 1644364800, 
1644364800, 1644364800, 1644364800, 1644364800, 1644364800, 1644364800, 
1644364800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 
1644796800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 1644796800, 1644969600, 1644969600, 
1644969600, 1644969600, 1644969600, 1644969600, 1644969600, 1644969600, 
1644969600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 
1645401600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 1645401600, 1645574400, 1645574400, 
1645574400, 1645574400, 1645574400, 1645574400, 1645574400, 1645574400, 
1645574400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 
1646006400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 1646006400, 1646179200, 1646179200, 
1646179200, 1646179200, 1646179200, 1646179200, 1646179200, 1646179200, 
1646179200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 
1646611200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 1646611200, 1646784000, 1646784000, 
1646784000, 1646784000, 1646784000, 1646784000, 1646784000, 1646784000, 
1646784000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 
1647216000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 1647216000, 1647388800, 1647388800, 
1647388800, 1647388800, 1647388800, 1647388800, 1647388800, 1647388800, 
1647388800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 
1647820800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 1647820800, 1647993600, 1647993600, 
1647993600, 1647993600, 1647993600, 1647993600, 1647993600, 1647993600, 
1647993600, 1648425600, 1648425600, 1648425600, 1648425600, 1648425600, 
1648425600, 1648425600, 1648425600, 1648425600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), WATERLEVEL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, 
-20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -40, -40, -40, -40, 
-40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, 
-40, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, 
-60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, 
-80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -105, 
-105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, 
-105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -105, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, 
-80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, -80, 
-60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -60, 
-60, -60, -60, -60, -60, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, 
-40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -40, -20, -20, -20, 
-20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, 
-20, -20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `CO2_micromol_m-2_s-1` = c("0.27139505741324671", "0.4157633359354288", 
"0.15992899812884132", "1.1194848273517737", "0.79075457861832099", 
"1.0775266537112769", "0.69476123175993199", "0.30893795890968201", 
"0.59072149896612691", "0.35554601623989524", "1.3780164782493001", 
"0.32628540738250833", "2.1095180646435194", "2.1600085134992844", 
"2.0155958086663537", "2.1077174157337994", "1.9632462135017583", 
"2.3180984283073878", "2.1064211587513051", "1.4358139521176683", 
"1.5066834793763968", "2.1369574079999478", "1.9195836017106582", 
"1.8052350538671498", "2.0440515776510302", "2.118608252224492", 
"2.1474083213584358", "1.7359304600000001", "1.756702041", "1.5409627299999999", 
"1.729111031", "1.7320159429999999", "1.5614416040000001", "2.2879506639999998", 
"2.4139872019999999", "1.682071627", "1.6448568580447556", "1.6889449664801475", 
"1.3711340429286729", "1.875717933753233", "1.6664328230324006", 
"1.5505666370924753", "2.6388012981467766", "2.1511187678475565", 
"1.9847250860660182", "1.8356646089999999", "2.1364581669999998", 
"2.143572802", "1.7975558540000001", "1.619482417", "1.6391889799999999", 
"2.5035888970000002", "2.5142764099999999", "1.680964232", "1.958719755", 
"2.2381542090000002", "2.0491134629999999", "1.743858525", "1.649061619", 
"1.52287843", "2.3599250629999999", "2.752085143", "1.83269349", 
"0.246117592", "2.3222614359999998", "2.0842279050000001", "1.61798218", 
"1.469827113", "1.209791807", "1.920288593", "2.3035356060000001", 
"1.679677946", "1.954561545", "2.510982582", "2.0548084809999998", 
"1.592419998", "1.3551681849999999", "1.2006259210000001", "1.9560248170000001", 
"2.4774309620000001", "1.511598333", "1.8978739179999999", "2.5299870659999999", 
"2.0845709559999999", "1.599516503", "1.410776061", "1.182287182", 
"1.8996466940000001", "2.1457103119999998", "1.4140874080000001", 
"1.963689912", "2.2892358920000002", "1.9326403139999999", "1.5217464510000001", 
"1.3767403300000001", "1.184099244", "1.83240136", "2.294201739", 
"1.578398298", "1.708733324", "1.9919294869999999", "1.911963332", 
"1.3849616709999999", "1.3491596370000001", "1.275689785", "1.855574719", 
"2.2881835129999999", "1.3628503759999999", "1.8881957460000001", 
"2.1822562140000001", "1.819324256", "1.6082268980000001", "1.4473207130000001", 
"1.2261625840000001", "1.6441516199999999", "2.2498499029999999", 
"1.3052630839999999", "1.5031692299999999", "1.5618497060000001", 
"1.353783395", "1.137173722", "1.3541515850000001", "1.242024961", 
"1.500667698", "2.452521398", "1.5782278750000001", "2.253915975", 
"2.2464840449999999", "1.7278589", "1.5360194469999999", "1.256435148", 
"1.1194851750000001", "1.589647204", "2.290152473", "1.33575117", 
"2.145376057", "2.1322964459999998", "1.857646482", "1.468899483", 
"1.2214986779999999", "1.0118496429999999", "1.614514926", "2.0071942329999999", 
"1.6689810389999999", "1.815169016", "1.8961425190000001", "1.68436502", 
"1.280998665", "1.156795606", "0.87616175500000004", "1.272030684", 
"1.8284124230000001", "1.5618653840000001", "1.8826223099978312", 
"1.7842623186324882", "1.4180668768461551", "1.2185402713490099", 
"0.99940916177110373", "0.71245831582815022", "0.95096171899781667", 
"1.5466542406093209", "1.2314730603686017", "1.5109331198663414", 
"1.2086227097116871", "1.0277781962724426", "0.89793474745842905", 
"0.92224588231443383", "0.60105706692259886", "0.69232229509682652", 
"1.3264090165356726", "1.0313635966293635", "0.98647292465773784", 
"1.0842308206412754", "0.94305566741682034", "0.72390255118967795", 
"0.83215480431567812", "0.54817644116952746", "0.65817686788826846", 
"1.0994303482204624", "1.6093932555079766", "0.43262916411282737", 
"0.53089870963876118", "0.29362447509960682", "0.46316608503584422", 
"0.66957007977545946", "0.44009381308666301", "0.99459465622162724", 
"0.81886598729349513", "0.50106313669593949", "0.78670571629779429", 
"0.7843702670374042", "0.45565443608459266", "0.72758696171600101", 
"0.64669464566838897", "0.7132354162154424", "1.1025274340563735", 
"0.80855344103069304", "0.48327113390191401"), `N2O_nmol_m-2_s-1` = c("4.0001453068505457", 
"2.1263921339006768", "1.6009816763147449", "6.9571368341868798", 
"22.89170781670143", "24.02733468660405", "13.025036613294411", 
"2.5261156442967869", "3.0158564915972277", "4.1817136472753571", 
"1.0195211515001792", "2.0943973515512662", "11.281200628420466", 
"4.6798244478809288", "3.6611605132622307", "9.8039901364713753", 
"1.9839228262573532", "1.9242828039226294", "3.3378611776882345", 
"0.69500614305794772", "1.4179367259377931", "8.2229976276622274", 
"4.87445520490059", "3.0984704840595914", "9.0645116994307386", 
"5.1233046409118845", "2.3325267205559377", "1.6393244419999999", 
"1.04369329", "0.64775313499999998", "3.3343406839999998", "3.8766776030000001", 
"1.3898519460000001", "8.6374156339999999", "5.6129796330000001", 
"2.7248588800000002", "1.7409642574031623", "1.1677835825391956", 
"0.52930648825269833", "3.1841719417718743", "3.3365498408294223", 
"1.1995701656807074", "9.8415525883603951", "5.0857271904783641", 
"3.3106477987330103", "2.441397399", "1.6169483360000001", "0.50979378900000005", 
"2.6383508569999998", "2.0296414239999998", "1.1306285030000001", 
"13.14234199", "6.546657154", "2.3305899129999998", "2.4042935929999998", 
"1.5512139030000001", "0.293575207", "2.0479204370000001", "1.2952943370000001", 
"0.90799539600000001", "14.58636802", "8.4433038160000002", "2.1517785699999998", 
"-1.8781112999999999E-2", "1.435046118", "0.201020006", "1.4717330580000001", 
"0.62430355500000001", "0.72464957299999999", "12.841292470000001", 
"7.56019007", "1.8448724439999999", "2.5705163789999999", "1.498432897", 
"0.13037274900000001", "1.407633387", "0.400680072", "0.73026709400000001", 
"12.887717589999999", "7.2444916949999998", "1.7545105649999999", 
"1.7607967390000001", "1.2244025789999999", "8.0806327999999997E-2", 
"1.320578802", "0.183280261", "0.66524531799999997", "9.6842091470000007", 
"4.3534296210000001", "1.503350486", "1.5591831810000001", "1.1755663949999999", 
"5.4900362000000001E-2", "1.2311752229999999", "0.14728957400000001", 
"0.63312293200000003", "9.0898057570000006", "3.6686423939999999", 
"1.7862696199999999", "1.014077449", "0.99321422999999998", "0.111415943", 
"0.92799312700000003", "0.121931227", "0.39021739700000002", 
"6.703758251", "2.008799094", "2.0688628480000002", "0.92345322200000002", 
"0.90557608300000003", "0.14645483500000001", "0.85801988600000001", 
"0.14603569199999999", "0.30769067700000002", "5.7014581209999999", 
"1.823611944", "1.9151560190000001", "0.42169903800000003", "0.44792936999999999", 
"0.32844379499999998", "0.498091483", "0.17677575000000001", 
"0.160728554", "5.0386189970000004", "2.168968338", "2.2567317729999998", 
"0.541707088", "0.59619073300000003", "0.48005946100000002", 
"0.52594131499999996", "0.26374192200000002", "0.27871760000000001", 
"5.2703013680000002", "2.1323220919999999", "2.5239165379999999", 
"0.31904312099999999", "0.58597121100000005", "1.034505982", 
"0.48816289099999999", "0.14858144500000001", "0.142905117", 
"4.5117802349999998", "1.8669765979999999", "2.9948042510000001", 
"0.23284223700000001", "0.42391237799999998", "1.338722446", 
"0.50074820399999997", "0.108086394", "0.129689843", "3.6974526750000001", 
"1.87332068", "2.8620819609999999", "0.12656566975013941", "0.39747475471751315", 
"1.6462206530510415", "0.32214392152029525", "0.14270487174995114", 
"9.4217489894026896E-2", "2.3481096887240178", "1.6379796495136676", 
"3.3591876401969425", "0.11291201431615748", "0.40340156526067206", 
"0.56444505143441004", "0.30686621155477184", "8.5022309733651852E-2", 
"0.17479809577647931", "2.0261843137856532", "1.4395749942457829", 
"3.4179319192051603", "1.190194020050001", "2.4116860199712367", 
"4.7938049804573453", "1.1830832532954203", "0.25011390459589977", 
"0.76430198318251574", "1.4034747612911189", "0.94637916028133895", 
"5.4011846165369359", "0.24574599232206479", "0.55744592265675919", 
"0.46865367012284809", "0.4280649700852785", "0.29047413065678934", 
"0.85565991952435905", "1.6259030689380469", "0.74506422304539066", 
"0.67681401535162711", "18.49175073219158", "14.56335917065674", 
"6.7610321187344553", "2.4317350856920315", "2.3800020151165007", 
"16.911049587263832", "32.78914711040467", "0.87054514117379", 
"3.5003002888631976"), `CH4_nmol_m-2_s` = c("-14.265953251894842", 
"-7.5488994214596854", "-8.6565410098711801", "-6.3476792860268096", 
"0.57660023092167045", "-0.67010072673405296", "-3.3747678545279851", 
"-1.0932821479912682", "-0.78452468762835736", "-0.30677508267720877", 
"-0.34776071569935135", "-0.36535483879873321", "-0.49072585765879723", 
"-1.821750758037826E-2", "2.825187216172341E-2", "1.8227983665593357", 
"0.29302296541213574", "0.25638496243112291", "4.3274393825826509", 
"-3.7235723513690742", "0.56015753402022017", "-6.6741411116958647", 
"-2.2077057850195572", "-1.8180634877001693", "68.0082157286175", 
"8.0798286913989301", "6.4917794511280063", "-2.0170701499999999", 
"-1.905610289", "-2.5385438090000001", "-5.1825874289999998", 
"4.2825988000000002E-2", "-0.89791764799999996", "42.984697400000002", 
"13.25003338", "4.0487472210000002", "0.32502724171377317", "5.9042431659574328", 
"26.720627046742276", "-0.55577860148021119", "0.20232964762715897", 
"-1.0493807350405806", "182.70729927485442", "7.5886887249175974", 
"5.3280383170358236", "-1.1773423430000001", "1.2586331559999999", 
"-3.0094242929999999", "-5.841645003", "0.42279492400000002", 
"-2.579726006", "151.49920990000001", "11.56616979", "7.8823326490000003", 
"4.614623559", "14.387732570000001", "1.3997811849999999", "0.69306013099999997", 
"1.3521720500000001", "-0.44908532099999998", "79.177510519999998", 
"14.22355694", "9.4502106799999996", "-4.0832317999999999E-2", 
"8.9597851049999999", "-1.2464582E-2", "-0.44140475200000001", 
"-0.273060794", "-0.65086403999999998", "28.084453360000001", 
"3.5771956509999998", "11.38376759", "9.2039327499999999", "18.266288840000001", 
"1.3789114579999999", "0.13807176199999999", "6.7495779000000006E-2", 
"-0.94072846700000001", "25.333527180000001", "4.49920191", "6.6092751319999996", 
"4.8108500999999998E-2", "6.2164605689999997", "7.5039939999999999E-2", 
"0.63027903600000001", "0.84909742600000004", "-0.47212448000000001", 
"10.063049700000001", "2.5329014779999999", "1.284553136", "-0.351092776", 
"4.5528773390000001", "1.147481663", "2.9527978250000002", "0.101919572", 
"-1.106550922", "6.2185377099999997", "6.7595844649999997", "1.220956835", 
"-0.125799884", "-0.15434520099999999", "-0.45456276400000001", 
"-0.29024857900000001", "0.46228170499999999", "-0.64464627200000002", 
"0.48647088199999999", "0.91988052799999998", "0.74963998600000004", 
"-0.438171325", "-0.689041024", "-0.61315711299999998", "-1.091276425", 
"-0.35291151100000001", "-0.88127678099999995", "-0.480667607", 
"-6.1773843000000002E-2", "0.46928782099999999", "-1.1000000000000001", 
"-0.64770404400000003", "-2.6544102239999998", "-1.6379862670000001", 
"-2.157884283", "-2.7247844470000002", "-1.58926553", "0.69023029700000005", 
"-1.3275259779999999", "-1.6798807659999999", "-1.9121202740000001", 
"-1.466319516", "-2.67952177", "-0.57801623300000005", "-0.97446570899999996", 
"-0.37682335", "-0.23307624499999999", "-1.924785535", "-2.2185686439999999", 
"-1.6377665939999999", "-2.053856498", "-2.0246783509999999", 
"-2.112852121", "-0.88533821400000001", "0.27953487500000002", 
"-0.34749129899999998", "-0.28648968699999999", "-1.2444698430000001", 
"-1.452754329", "-0.63782489899999995", "-1.3449811549999999", 
"-1.626081468", "-1.4574623980000001", "-0.76345194599999999", 
"-1.0940807960000001", "-0.15453839899999999", "-2.4928170142450625", 
"-1.7674056656435833", "-1.5867048015453278", "-2.302014580334327", 
"-2.8733550557924672", "-1.4826352481672562", "1.7029838147928458", 
"9.5599563459854888", "-1.1082981993579326", "-1.1496243675416329", 
"-1.5543776488453871", "-1.3873455297827455", "-1.6487886553906126", 
"-1.9067688386143626", "-1.7033804482965871", "-0.62404098969253174", 
"0.25833137696013592", "-2.1733615946014306", "-1.1506068970222647", 
"-2.5385038442312418", "-2.2321463793117218", "-1.3698962752331245", 
"-1.8464726396967333", "-0.64976515586023809", "-1.1670843078524353", 
"-1.2140804304137236", "-4.5261068466370817", "-3.6939969669462904", 
"-4.5737040154747826", "-2.0084163503420722", "-2.9244909000107477", 
"-4.6594237848283271", "-1.5749991916271791", "23.30132180080723", 
"-10.992551090225485", "-7.8652028683896402", "-6.6234187866908627", 
"-5.0764643470084652", "-4.2707199163382175", "-4.1801049143857041", 
"-1.0628137999090299", "-1.2151240119362672", "6.9230866768267818", 
"-2.5334133698090744", "-0.20533934752525138")), class = c("tbl_time", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -198L), index_quo = ~DATE, index_time_zone = "UTC")
```

**The code:**

```
res.aov <- anova_test(data = flux_CO2_bare_columns, dv = `CO2_micromol_m-2_s-1`  , wid = ID, within = c(WATERLEVEL, TRAJECT, LOCATION, MEASUREMENT))
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

I hope someone can help me to finialize my statistical analyses.

Comment: Can you trim down the code to the bare minimum that will produce the error? For example, we don't need the code in which you read from Excel, and any data cleaning. Just run `dput()` on the cleaned dataset.

Comment: Is this beter ?